# setting particular part of the tool tip text to be bold with different font color

Tags: asp.net, tooltip

i have tool tip for an image in asn asp.net & c#.net  and i want to set particular part of the tool tip text to be bold with different font color,

how can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some nice CSS-only tooltip behavior which you could use to customize your tooltips: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo.html which is done by using `:hover` selector for `span` element inside `a`.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://sample.com/">Links<span>Tooltip text</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
div#links a span {display: none;} // hide our tooltip SPAN.
div#links a:hover span {
  display: block; // show our tooltip
  // position/style tool-tip here.
}
```

Try including a `<span>bold text here</span>` within the tooltip span from this example and style it appropriately with css. Such as

```
div#links a span span {font-weight: bold;}
```

A simpler example [here.](http://psacake.com/web/jl.asp). In this example you would add the following style instead:

```
a.info span span {font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote Alexei, and for the edit. However, in English the proper spelling of customize is "customise" and behavior is "behaviour". I think your spell-checker is set to American.