# asp.net c# show tooltip in bold

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I am trying to show a tooltip within my codebehind. (I am using ASP.NET C#)
What I like to do is to show part of the tooltip in bold as such:
I have the following:

```
     header["Emp"].ToolTip = "Employee<b>Number</b>";
```

it doesn't seem to work as the what it shows is:

```
    Employee<b>Number</b>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `ToolTip` is the tooltip of the client's OS. So you cannot change that from server. You could use a custom div instead with appropriate CSS.

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178377/setting-particular-part-of-the-tool-tip-text-to-be-bold-with-different-font-colo

Comment: You should use javascript instead. Just because it is a client side response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot display bold tooltips in the way in which you are trying to do.

`Tooltip` property renders as a [`title`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp) attribute on the HTML element, which [doesn't support formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484137/is-it-possible-to-format-an-html-tooltip).

If you wish to format your tooltip you should use a javascript tooltip alternative.

Here is a link to a popular tooltip jQuery plugin which I have had good experience with:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

---

So that your client-side can access this data, I would add it as a HTML5 [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attribute, and read from that:

```
header["Emp"].Attributes["data-tooltip"] = "Employee<b>Number</b>";
```